# Using CloudHSM from Ruby via OpenSSL for Net::HTTP

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, ssl, openssl, aws-sdk

I'd like to use CloudHSM to store an X509 Certificate and an associated private key that I'm using for an SSL connection through Net::HTTP. However, the documentation I've found for doing this with Ruby is pretty sparse. Currently, I'm setting up a connection like this:

```
Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port).tap do |config|
    config.use_ssl = true
    config.cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(ENV['PUBLIC_KEY'])
    config.key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(ENV['PRIVATE_KEY'])
end
```

Assuming that I've added the cert and the key to CloudHSM and that I've followed the [OpenSSL engine install directions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudhsm/latest/userguide/openssl-library-install.html), I think I need to do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31545395/how-to-use-a-custom-openssl-engine-for-nethttp) to get the cert and key out. Specifically, I'd change the above to:

```
Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port).tap do |config|
  config.use_ssl = true
  config.cert = get_the_cert_somehow
  config.key = OpenSSL::Engine.by_id("cloudhsm").load_private_key("LABEL=private_key_label")
end
```

My questions are:

1. Is this actually how I should go about this?
2. If so, what do I do for `get_the_cert_somehow`? Do I need to use the [AWS SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/CloudHSMV2/Types/Certificates.html)? It feels like there should be a way to do this through the OpenSSL library, but I'm not seeing it.
3. Is there something else am I missing? (I'm just starting to dig into this CloudHSM and OpenSSL stuff)

Comment: Not sure if you are aware... the certificate is a *public* entity.  It doesn't need to be handled or stored securely.   You hand it over to your peer every time you negotiate, and it's meaningless without the matching key.

Comment: Good point @Michael-sqlbot . So, I should be able to just leave that bit as-is, I imagine. How about the other questions?

Comment: I wish I could, but I'm afraid neither Ruby nor CloudHSM are within my scope.